# Macbook Air's trackpad on trains

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad

Is there any known issue with using a laptop's trackpad while on a moving train, i.e. is the EM field expected to interfere?

I ask because often when I use my Apple Macbook Air 1.1 (Early 2008) trackpad on a train (as opposed to, e.g., on my office desk) I get interferences of various kinds: it is slower in moving, it makes strange effects like activating auxiliary functions when I put two fingers on it, etc.

Comment: I've never experienced it. Are you sure it isn't more because of a different temperature of the device for example (which would be normal behavior)?

Comment: @KevinGrabher I don't notice particular temperature differences between train and office usage. Do you have the same machine 1.1 from Early 2008? It might also be a malfunction of my particular hardware

Comment: No. All models, or trackpads for that matter react to temperature.

Comment: Have you noticed the issue when the macbook was still new or did it just start recently?

Comment: @KevinGrabher as far as I remember, only recently I started using it on trains, and I soon noticed this behavior